# Java How would you use instanceof to return a new object types?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

if you have the following

1. Interface: Meal
2. Hotdog implements Meal
3. Burger implements Meal
4. Salad implements Meal

How would you create a method to take in one of these object types to return the appropriate object?

Example:

```
Method makeFood(HotDog)

if(HotDog instanceof Meal)
 return new HotdogObject();
```

How do you correctly do this?

I'm working with

```
static public Food createMeal(Meal f)
      throws Exception
  {

    if (f instanceof Hotdog)
    {
      return f = new HotDog();
    }
    if (f instanceof Burger)
    {
      return f = new Burger();
    }

    throw new Exception("NotAFood!");
  }
```

Comment: Unless `Hotdog` and `Burger` extend / implement `Food`, this example will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly you are confusing classes with their instances. The `instanceof` operator, as its name says, verifies that an object is an instance of a class, not that a class is a subclass of another. Your particular problem would be solved most elegantly by resorting to reflection:

```
public static <T extends Meal> T createMeal(Class<T> c) {
  try { return c.newInstance(); }
  catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

For example, if you want a `Burger`, you call

```
Burger b = createMeal(Burger.class);
```

But, if you really wanted just another instance of the same type as an instance that you already have, then the code would be

```
public static Meal createMeal(Meal x) {
  try { return x.getClass().newInstance(); }
  catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Comment: What would be the proper approach to this. I dont think reflection is what I want even though it seems to be the answer to the question I posted. I want know how do this the proper OOP way

Comment: You want the first way, specifying just the object type via a `class` literal? In that case, there really is no way. If you supply an existing instance, then the proper OOP way would be for `Meal` to have a method for this purpose, like `anotherInstance`, and each class would implement it accordingly. Polymorphism can only work if you already have an instance of your type.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want something like this?

```
if(f.getClass().isAssignableFrom(HotDog.class))
   return new HotdogObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are referring to reflection.
look at this link
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

   public class constructor2 {
      public constructor2()
      {
      }

  public constructor2(int a, int b)
  {
     System.out.println(
       "a = " + a + " b = " + b);
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     try {
       Class cls = Class.forName("constructor2");
       Class partypes[] = new Class[2];
        partypes[0] = Integer.TYPE;
        partypes[1] = Integer.TYPE;
        Constructor ct 
          = cls.getConstructor(partypes);
        Object arglist[] = new Object[2];
        arglist[0] = new Integer(37);
        arglist[1] = new Integer(47);
        Object retobj = ct.newInstance(arglist);
     }
     catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Class's class method : `static Class<?> forName(String class_name)`

for returning the object of the class that matches the instanceof condition.